# Node.js Express JS

Tags: node.js

My search query for mongodb is not working. I don't know what is wrong.

```
var data = "/"+ req.param('search') +"/";

db.collection("user_info").find({name: { $regex: data }})
```

Comment: Define 'not working'. Do you get an error? Do you not get the expected results? This question could do with a little more detail.

Comment: No error, but no expected results.

Comment: where is return callback

Comment: i think you should put little more code snippet to get insight of your issue.. looks there is no call back for find

Comment: when i put text in search data that work correctly

Comment: Try not to wrap your string with `"/"`. Pass it as is. Wrapping a string with backslashes wont convert variable string to a regex. So those `/str/` become part of a pattern.

Comment: when I put search data as below, the result come out correctly

db.collection("user_info").find({name: { $regex: /searchData/ }})

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation the `$regex` parameter needs a correct regular expression or a string. If you pass a string you have to omit the slash.

RegEx

```
{ $regex: /searchString/ }
```

String

```
{ $regex: 'searchString' }
```

[MongoDB Manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)